# Finding the best selling item for each of your best customers in SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I have 3 tables: Products (prod_id, prod_name, prod_price), Customers (cust_id, address, email, name), and Sales (sale_id, cust_id, prod_id).

I wrote a query to find the top 100 customers (in terms of money spent):

```
SELECT TOP 100 C.name AS customer_name,
SUM(P.prod_price) AS total_spent
FROM customers C
LEFT JOIN Sales S ON C.cust_id=S.cust_id
LEFT JOIN Products P ON S.prod_id=P.prod_id
GROUP BY C.cust_id
ORDER BY total_spent DESC;
```

Now I would like to write a query that will tell me the top seller for each of those 100 customers but I can't figure it out. I tried to write a nested query, but it is not working:

```
SELECT P.prod_name as best_seller,
C.name AS customer_name
FROM Product P
LEFT JOIN Sales S ON P.prod_id=S.prod_id
LEFT JOIN Customers C on S.cust_id = C.cust_id
GROUP BY C.name, P.prod_name
WHERE C.name IN
    (SELECT C.name AS customer_name
     FROM customers C
     LEFT JOIN Sales S ON C.cust_id=S.cust_id
     LEFT JOIN Products P ON S.prod_id=P.prod_id
     GROUP BY C.cust_id
     ORDER BY total_spent DESC
     LIMIT 100);
```

I am ultimately going to run these queries on a 10gb dataset using sql, but I have been testing them in SQlite on a really small subset so that I don't have to spin up an instance until I'm pretty sure they work (hence the LIMIT 100 syntax). In SQLite, the only error I get is "near "WHERE": syntax error".

Comment: How do you define "top seller"?

Comment: Good question, I was not clear. I am hoping to retrieve the one they bought the most of, not necessarily the one they spent the most money on.

Comment: WHERE should be before GROUP BY.

Comment: Of course! Thank you. I guess I got where confused with having? I don't know why I wanted to put it before group by.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking something more along these lines:

```
SELECT TOP (100) cp.*
FROM (SELECT c.cust_id, c.name, p.prod_id, p.prod_name, 
             SUM(P.prod_price) AS product_spend,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.cust_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum,
             SUM(SUM(p.prod_price)) OVER (PARTITION BY c.cust_id) as total_spent
      FROM customers C JOIN
           Sales S
           ON C.cust_id = S.cust_id JOIN
           Products P
           ON S.prod_id = P.prod_id
      GROUP BY C.cust_id, p.prod_id, p.prod_name
     ) cp
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY total_spent DESC;
```

This aggregates once by customer and product.  It uses window functions to get the total per customer and then filters and sorts in the outer query.

Use `COUNT(*)` in the `ORDER BY` to get "bought the most of".  Use `SUM(p.prod_price)` to get "spent the most on".